# Self hosted SignalR running under SSL - access denied error

Tags: https, signalr, owin, self-hosting, katana

I'm currently working on a project where I have a SignalR hub self hosted in a Windows Service. For the SignalR hub I want to expose 2 bindings - one HTTP and one HTTPS. 
I've followed Rick Strahl's tutorial (http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/23/Hosting-SignalR-under-SSLhttps) and managed to get the HTTP binding working fine.
However, the HTTPS one is not working although I've ran the netsh http add sslcert in various possible ways...
The exception I get is Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied    at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()

I suspect this is due to the fact that my windows service runs under a specific user account. For the HTTP binding I ran the netsh http add urlacl for the port I needed and for the user account that I use. 
However, the netsh http add sslcert doesn't have any user option...

Did anybody run into this issue before? Any suggestions are welcomed as I am stuck and confused at this moment.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Andrei

Answer (score 1):

ok.. problem solved quite easily... All I had to do was to run the netsh http add urlacl for the url I wanted and set the user. Initially I didn't realize that I can do that for a HTTPS binding.

Comment: I've followed the same instructions from the url in the question,
also added the urlacl as above suggestion.
however now I receive "System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'https://*:8082/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine."
any suggestions?